# Storing list or array inside Realm Model ? [ Swift ]

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to store List inside realm model, app is crashing .

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class DirectoryListResponse:Object,Codable {
    dynamic var neighbours:List<Directory>?
    dynamic var management:List<Directory>?
    dynamic var emergency:List<Directory>?
}
```

Storing:

```
try? self.realm?.write {
      if let dic = self.directories
       {
         self.realm?.add(dic)
         }
   }
```

**Note:**
I am able to store the mode which has only String ,Int , Bool , only facing problem when model contains List. my Question is

**1. Can we store List in model ?**

**2. if not then what is work around for this , if yes then how can i do this ?**

**Crash Log:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Table has no columns
Exception backtrace:
0   Realm                               0x0000000102393f91 _ZN5realm4util6detail26ExceptionWithBacktraceBaseC2Ev + 49
1   Realm                               0x00000001023bcb96 _ZN5realm4util22ExceptionWithBacktraceISt9exceptionEC2IJEEEDpOT_ + 38
2   Realm                               0x00000001023bcb42 _ZN5realm10LogicErrorC2ENS0_9ErrorKindE + 34
3   Realm                               0x00000001023bcabb _ZN5realm10LogicErrorC1ENS0_9ErrorKindE + 27
4   Realm                               0x000000010297b5ac _ZN5realm5Table16insert_empty_rowEmm + 268
5   Realm                               0x0000000102a3c759 _ZN5realm4sync13create_objectERKNS0_14TableInfoCacheERNS_5TableE + 137
6   Realm                               0x00000001025576d4 _ZN5realm6Object6createIU8__strongP11objc_object18RLMAccessorContextEES0_RT0_RKNSt3__110shared_ptrINS_5RealmEEERKNS_12ObjectSchemaET_bbmPNS_8BasicRowINS_5TableEEE + 2452
7   Realm                               0x0000000102556b6a RLMAddObjectToRealm + 682
8   RealmSwift                          0x0000000103be57af $s10RealmSwift0A0C3add_6updateyAA6ObjectC_AC12UpdatePolicyOtF + 1407
9   RealmSwift                          0x0000000103be5c98 $s10RealmSwift0A0C3add_6updateyx_AC12UpdatePolicyOtSTRzAA6ObjectC7ElementRczlF + 536
10  MyApp                            0x0000000101b9dfb8 $s8MyApp9DBManagerC6insert4dataySayxG_t10RealmSwift6ObjectCRbzlFyyXEfU_ + 248
11  MyApp                            0x0000000101b9e040 $s8MyApp9DBManagerC6insert4dataySayxG_t10RealmSwift6ObjectCRbzlFyyXEfU_TA + 32
12  RealmSwift                          0x0000000103be49ea $s10RealmSwift0A0C5writeyyyyKXEKF + 90
13  MyApp                            0x0000000101b9ddc8 $s8MyApp9DBManagerC6insert4dataySayxG_t10RealmSwift6ObjectCRbzlF + 264
14  MyApp                            0x0000000101ad62be $s8MyApp11DirectoryVMC14getDirectories7handleryySb_SStc_tFyAA8ResponseVyAA0b4ListG0CGcfU_ + 414
15  MyApp                            0x0000000101ad6545 $s8MyApp11DirectoryVMC14getDirectories7handleryySb_SStc_tFyAA8ResponseVyAA0b4ListG0CGcfU_TA + 21
16  MyApp                            0x0000000101ad67ea $s8MyApp8ResponseVyAA013DirectoryListB0CGIegg_AFIegn_TR + 58
17  MyApp                            0x0000000101ad6851 $s8MyApp8ResponseVyAA013DirectoryListB0CGIegg_AFIegn_TRTA + 17
18  MyApp                            0x0000000101b666f8 $s8MyApp10APIServiceC9parseData6urlStr10parameters10methodType7showHud14successHandler07failureM0ySS_SDySSypGSg9Alamofire10HTTPMethodOSbyAA8ResponseVyxGcySSctSeRzlFZyAM0dQ0VyypGcfU_ + 2456
19  MyApp                            0x0000000101b66fba $s8MyApp10APIServiceC9parseData6urlStr10parameters10methodType7showHud14successHandler07failureM0ySS_SDySSypGSg9Alamofire10HTTPMethodOSbyAA8ResponseVyxGcySSctSeRzlFZyAM0dQ0VyypGcfU_TA + 58
20  Alamofire                           0x00000001020aecdb $s9Alamofire11DataRequestC8response5queue0D10Serializer17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_E0CSg_xyAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGctAA0bkF8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_ + 411
21  Alamofire                           0x00000001020b7e68 $s9Alamofire11DataRequestC8response5queue0D10Serializer17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_E0CSg_xyAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGctAA0bkF8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_TA + 40
22  Alamofire                           0x00000001020676fd $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 45
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108462d7f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108463db5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108471080 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1540
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054278a9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105421f56 __CFRunLoopRun + 2310
28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105421302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
29  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010beb42fe GSEventRunModal + 65
30  UIKitCore                           0x000000010e8c9ba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
31  MyApp                            0x0000000101b84fab main + 75
32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001084d8541 start + 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists cannot be optional. All lists in realm are required.

Also, your properties need to be visible to obj-c. I like to use `@objcMembers` on the class but you can also use `@objc` before each property if you prefer.

See the docs here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#models